# I would retrieve friendMemberList by using friend operation but i had always a last member of list?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

```
@RequestMapping(value="/facebook/friendlist", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showFeed(Model model) {
    List<Reference> friendLists = facebook.friendOperations().getFriendLists();
    model.addAttribute("friendLists", friendLists);



    //retourner les membres d'amis de la liste 
    for (int i =0; i< friendLists.size() ;i++) {
        System.out.println(friendLists.size());
    List<Reference> friendListMembers= facebook.friendOperations().getFriendListMembers(friendLists.get(i).getId());
    model.addAttribute("friendListMembers", friendListMembers);
    System.out.println(friendLists.get(i).getId());
    System.out.println(friendListMembers);  
    }
```

I think the problem is in the jsp page,
How to solve this.
thanks in advance

Comment: It's really not clear what you're doing here or what the problem is

Comment: and the jsp page:<ul class="friendlist">

<c:forEach items="${friendLists}" var="friendList">
 <h3>*********</h3>
 <li><c:out value="${friendList.id}"/>
 <c:out value="${friendList.name}"/><h3>*********</h3>
 </li>
    <ul class="friendListMembers">
         <c:forEach items="${friendListMembers}" var="friendListMember">
 
    <li>
    <c:out value="${friendListMember.id}"/>
    <c:out value="${friendListMember.name}"/></li>
   </c:forEach> 
 </ul>

</c:forEach>

Comment: I have memberFriendList of last idFriendList

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the value of `friendListMembers` in your model, so only the last entry in the `friendLists` array will have its members available in JSP code.

You need a 2-D array in the model, with the key being the Friend List ID, and the value being the array of members of that Friend List

Simple Example:

In your java code:

```
ArrayList<String,List> allFriends = new ArrayList();

for (int i =0; i< friendLists.size() ;i++) {
    String friendListId = friendLists.get(i).getId();
    List<Reference> friendListMembers= facebook.friendOperations().getFriendListMembers(friendListId);
    allFriends.add(friendListId, friendListMembers);
    }
    model.addAttribute("allFriends", allFriends);
```

In your JSP code:

```
<c:forEach items="${allFriends}" var="list">
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="friend">
            <c:out value="${friend.id}"/>:<c:out value="${friend.name}"/><br/>
        </c:forEach>
        <hr/>
</c:forEach>
```

Note, I have not tested this and would be surprised if it works when copy/pasted, it's just an idea to get you on the right track

Comment: Sorry you mean use two "for" , I don't understand Could you help me how to implement this?